# Pydev Showing Errors for @staticmethod Reimplementation

Tags: python, methods, static, decorator

I have wanted to create a python decorator that performs a particular task, but also does what @staticmethod does.  I have accomplished this, but using PyDev, it tells me that the usage is incorrect, because the method does not have the self parameter.

My simplified implementation is below:

```
class Service(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.f
```

and the usage is:

```
class Environment:

    @Service
    def getConfig(input):
        return 50
```

When I run this python program, everything runs well, but PyDev thinks it's an error.  Is there some easy way to disable checking for this type of error in pydev, while keeping the rest of its functionality present?

Comment: You could also consider using two decorators - chaining @staticmethod and @Service (which could then probably also be a function). Personally I also think that a decorator should use the method/function/module naming convention; `service` rather than `Service`. (Consider that `staticmethod` is a class.)

Answer (score 1):

As usual, found it before anybody could answer.

But if anybody in the future wants to know:

Window > Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Code Analysis > Others

This window is self-explanatory.